# Show blocking message box

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Is there something similar to CWaitCursor that shows message box instead of cursor animation?

In my MFC GUI application I want to show message box saying "Please wait..." before calling long running function and then close the message box after function completes. User shouldn't be able to dismiss message box.

Thank you.

Comment: This could be quite easily done as a simple dialog box, although I would at least offer a cancel button to allow the user to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a non modal Dialog box, or a simple popup window with a static control in it.
The trick is to use UpdateWindow/RedrawWindow to bring it into the view and force window to update it.

A Problem might occur when you program is Long running and doesn't pump any Messages in. This case the window might be covered and uncovered and without a message Loop it will not be painted again.

So may create the new window, set the focus to it and disable the main window. Than you can pump Messages when lengthy Operation starts.

Easier might be to put the lengthy Operation in a second thread and show the dialog with a message Loop in the main thread, that's waiting on the process to end.